# Is there an evolutionary advantage to bees to becoming docile when exposed to smoke?

Tags: evolution, bees

I have not seen other research on this on line, it occurred to me though that this physiological behavior / stimulus-response of bees (calm down when exposed to smoke) might be a subject for original research, and understanding how benefits of this behavior may be applicable to human group psychology as well is another possible avenue of research.

An initial thought, perhaps the colony would better weather forest fires docile and hunkered down in a hive/ground/tree than reacting aggressively, or it may be a matter of another mechanism piggybacked on this response to sensory stimuli that is beneficial to the colony...or worker bee.

I'm just throwing this question out there, in the event that there is a theory or "answer".

Comment: There has been research done on this, and it's easy to find. Have you googled, "Why does smoke make bees docile"? If you have, please edit your question to improve it, because I can't see any application for it to human behavior.

Comment: You also might wonder what kind of Q&A site this is, getting such feedback. Aren't we supposed to just answer your question? Actually, no. We're expected to help if we so choose. We're scientists or people interested in science, a lot of us teach, practice, or research some aspect of Biology. We expect some meaningful degree of research; not a ton, but not nothing, either. Biology students need to learn how to find information. Consider this kind of like a classroom, not a chat room. You'll get a better response to your question with a better effort.